# Basic Activity in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I've built broadcast reciever as my first class in my project, after i've finished him
I added new Activity Class (include the manifest.xml) and i want that this activity will be the main class thats start, but i cant reach it from my device becuase only the broadcastreciever is working.

Thanks

Comment: You're trying to start an Activity from your BroadcastReceiver? The question is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make this activity HOME...or main class add this in your manifest for the activity

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```